# Is there a way to change settings (e.g. color scheme) in a running tmux session triggered by a certain shell command (e.g. ssh)?

Tags: hook, config, tmux

I just found out about the possibility of hooks in tmux. Since I'm still very new to the command line (and therefore not used to (say need time to) read through all relevant parts of a manpage) I just quickly wanted to ask here, if it is possible to use bash commands to trigger (e.g. when I use ssh, I want to change the color of my status bar). (Although I fear it is not possible).

If not, what could be a way to achieve what I want? Can I make an alias for the command in question and 'reload' a different .tmux.conf file (in a current session)?

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**

For example:

I have two versions of a program where I source different environmental variables via aliases (say progVersionA and progVersionB).

When I have a tmux session running, I would like the current 'sourced' environment shown in the status bar (say "progVersionA"). And as soon as I switch to the other program the status bar should read "progVersionB". So, what I want is, that the status bar changes as soon as I run the alias progVersionB.

Comment: When you say triggered by a certain shell command, do you mean tmux running in an ssh session, or when ssh is started on the same machine that tmux is running on? In either case, both are possible; please clarify.

Comment: see my edit above